# What is the best way to match html text that is outside of an html tag in Go?

Tags: html, regex, go

I have a bunch of html I am parsing and I need to remove certain `<a>` tags if they contain certain text. Normally, I'd use Goquery BUT the text I am searching for often falls outside the html tag itself. For instance, this html:

```
<html><body>
This is the start.            
<a href="http://example.com/path">We don't want to match this text.</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/another/path" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 'sans-serif'; color:#838383;font-size:12px; line-height:14px"></a> match this text.<a href="blah">We also don't want to match this text</a>
</body></html>
```

I am using this regexp but it is failing and matching the text I don't want to match:

```
(?is)<a[^>]+href=["'](?P<link>.*?)["']*.?> match this text\.
```

https://regex101.com/r/iEXpqc/1

Comment: `.` matches any char. Actually, you still should consider some HTML parser. If you want to use a regex, you should think of some workarounds with negated character classes, see [an example](https://regex101.com/r/iEXpqc/2).

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking the same but couldn't figure it out with Goquery. The example posted matches the wrong text, btw.

Comment: Yeah, it is not quite clear anyway what the criteria for a match are.

Comment: Have you considered an XPath package? XPath can be a little horrific but it does support looking inside text nodes.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) (not [go](/questions/tagged/go), but the logic can be re-implemented):

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//a[contains(text(), "want to match")]' file.html
```

### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
  <body>
This is the start.  

<a href="http://www.example.com/another/path" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, 'sans-serif'; color:#838383;font-size:12px; line-height:14px"/> match this text.
</body>
</html>
```

### Note

- add `-L` switch if you want to replace *on the fly*